# Nomad not mounting local directory inside container properly

Tags: caddy, hashicorp, nomad

I am trying to run Caddy using Nomad. I basically write the config file to the local directory and then try to mount that inside the container but every time I get the error

```
run: reading config file: open /data/Caddyfile: no such file or directory
run: reading config file: open /data/Caddyfile: no such file or directory
run: reading config file: open /data/Caddyfile: no such file or directory
```

I am running Nomad itself on Docker as well but not sure if that has anything to do with this issue.

Here is my job file

```
job "ingress" {
  datacenters = ["dc1"]
  type        = "service"

  group "proxy" {
    count = 1

    network {
      mode = "host"
      port  "ingressHttp"{
         static = 80
         to = 80
      }
      port  "ingressHttps"{
         static = 443
         to = 443
      }
    }

    service {
      name = "http"
      provider = "nomad"
      port = "ingressHttp"
    }
    service {
      name = "https"
      provider = "nomad"
      port = "ingressHttps"
    }

    task "server" {
      driver = "docker"
      config {
        image = "caddy/caddy:2.2.1-alpine"
        ports = [
          "ingressHttp",
          "ingressHttps"
        ]
        volumes = ["local:/data"]
        args = [
          "caddy",
          "run",
          "--config",
          "/data/Caddyfile",
          "--adapter",
          "caddyfile",
        ]
      }
      resources {
        cpu    = 1000
        memory = 2048
      }
      template {
        data = <<EOH
        domain.com {
          reverse_proxy 0.0.0.0:26134 {
            header_down Strict-Transport-Security max-age=31536000
          }
        }

        EOH

        destination = "local/Caddyfile"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Try mounting the file. `volumes = ["local/Caddyfile:/data/Caddyfile"]`. I copied your file and was able to run with no problems on nomad v1.7.2 on archlinux. What is your environment? The official  caddy config https://github.com/hashicorp/nomad-pack-community-registry/blob/main/packs/caddy/templates/caddy.nomad.tpl#L90 just mounts to /etc/caddy

Comment: @KamilCuk Let me try that. I am running Nomad on Docker and its not installed on the host. I wonder if thats messing up the file locations and stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it is because I was running Nomad from docker and that is an unsupported configuration with all sorts of unforeseen side effects.